# application that copies all links in a web page

Tags: automation

I have to download something and those 100+ links to megaupload are all in the same webpage.
Do you know of a better way of copying those links instead of copy and pasting them one by one?
So that it will accumulate all the links, or portion of the links that I want to get and copy it all in the clipboard then just paste it on the download manager. For windows xp or 7

Comment: hmmm there are firefox plugins that can do this... lets see if I can find one...

Comment: wait... do you just want a text file that has all the links? please clarify.

Comment: Either? http://superuser.com/questions/133214/extract-links-and-save-pages http://superuser.com/questions/71347/what-are-good-link-extractors-out-there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera can do this. Open the page in Opera, press Ctrl + Shift + L, select all entries, and press Ctrl + C.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can help you

1. [**Flashgot**](http://flashgot.net/), a Firefox add-on
2. [**InternetDownloadManager**](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) or [**Flashget**](http://www.flashget.com/index_en.htm), Windows application

Answer (score 1):

[LinkSidebar](http://linksidebar.mozdev.org/) will let you copy any or all of the links on a page at once.

Comment: this does not work with the latest versions of firefox